# In a construct "but it is the X who ... that Y" can ending "s" really be omitted on a verb Y belonging to a 3rd person singular noun X in this case?

Tags: tenses, bare-infinitive, third-person

> The ocean's depths hold secrets yet to be discovered, but it is the sailor who braves the storms that uncover them.

This sentence was generated by ChatGPT and the bot claims that ‘uncover’ verb belongs to the ‘sailor’ and that it is a valid English sentence, despite the absence of ‘s’ in the end of the verb, because *"uncover is a bare infinitive"*.

Can this sentence, the way it's phrased, really mean that it is the sailor who uncovers the secrets? I would normally put an ‘s’ in the end of ‘uncover’ as I recognize it as a 3rd person singular verb in present tense:

> The ocean's depths hold secrets yet to be discovered, but it is the sailor who braves the storms that uncover**s** them.

Which is the right way? The

> ..., but it is the sailor who ... that uncover them.

or the

> ..., but it is the sailor who ... that uncovers them.

Or are they both correct perhaps?

---

A bit of clarification from the bot, it seems to mean "that is able to uncover" by the "that uncover" part:

> Certainly! Here is the saying about the ocean that I came up with earlier: "The ocean's depths hold secrets yet to be discovered, but it is the sailor who braves the storms that uncover them." This saying suggests that the ocean's depths contain secrets that have not yet been discovered, and that it is the sailor who is brave enough to endure and navigate through difficult storms that is able to uncover these secrets. The storms serve as a metaphor for the challenges and obstacles that must be overcome in order to discover something new or uncover something that was previously hidden. I hope this helps! Is there anything else I can help with?

Comment: It should be _uncovers_ because, as you point out, _sailor_ is singular. So it made a mistake. GPTs make lots of mistakes.

Comment: Humans make similar mistakes, though, whereby a finite verb agrees in number with the nearest preceding noun (here *storms)* and not with its proper subject.  In the 1952 D'Oyly Carte recording of Gilbert & Sullivan's *Ruddigore,* for instance, Fancourt sings "And then each ghost, with his lady-toast, to their churchyard beds *take* flight," though Gilbert had correctly written "takes" there.

Comment: @Brian Huh, that's a weird one. At first I thought the error was related to distributivity because of "each", but "each ghost take flight" doesn't sound right. Now I'm thinking it's actually because of "their", which implies a plural subject: "**[they]** to their churchyard beds take flight", referring to the ghost and lady. Because otherwise you'd keep a singular subject by writing "to *his* churchyard beds takes flight". I'm not familiar with the play, though.

Comment: What question did you ask such that the bot generated that sentence and analyzed it as well?

Comment: From the bot: *I apologize for any confusion that my previous response may have caused. In the sentence "The ocean's depths hold secrets yet to be discovered, but it is the sailor who braves the storms that uncover them," the verb "uncover" should actually be in the singular form to agree with the singular subject "sailor." The correct sentence would be: "The ocean's depths hold secrets yet to be discovered, but it is the sailor who braves the storms that uncovers them."

I apologize for the error in my previous response. Thank you for bringing this to my attention....*

Comment: After some more analysis and reading the answers, I think the message is that the _process_ of "the sailor braving the storms" is what "uncovers them", not the "sailor" himself. Though I still wonder if "s" is not required when "that" refers to a process.

Answer (score 10):

The sentence in the OP is actually not as simple as we might think. The sentence reads:

> The ocean's depths hold secrets yet to be discovered, but it is the
> sailor who braves the storms that uncover them.

The heart of the question is, should we say 'uncover' or 'uncovers'? It depends what we want to communicate.

If we mean that the storms uncover the secrets, then there is no s, because storms is plural. One storm uncovers; many storms uncover. So the sentence would be correct. (But note that the reasoning given by the bot is wrong. 'Uncover' is not an infinitive. it's simply a verb matched correctly to its subject within its clause.)

If on the other hand we mean that the sailor does the uncovering, then the grammar is wrong, because sailor is singular and requires the singular verb 'uncovers'.

So which one is it? It turns out that question is not so easy to answer, because there are issues with other parts of the sentence as well. We see this if we try some rewrites of the sentence:

1. The ocean's depths hold secrets yet to be discovered, but it is the sailor who braves the storms who uncovers them.
2. The ocean's depths hold secrets yet to be discovered, but it is the sailor who braves the storms.
3. The ocean's depths hold secrets yet to be discovered, but it is the storms that uncover them.
4. The ocean's depths hold secrets yet to be discovered, but it is the sailor who braves the storms that uncover them who gets the treasure.

If I wanted to be clear that the sailor was uncovering, I would repeat 'who' in the two clauses, as in example 1. The sailor **who** braves the storm is also the sailor **who** uncovers the secrets. The change from 'who' to 'that' is as much a clue to a change of subject as the change from singular to plural.

Examples 2-4 show the problem with simply applying the last clause to 'the storms' without further thought. If we do that, what is the point of referring to the sailor at all? Example 3 makes perfect sense by itself: The ocean hides secrets, but the storms uncover those secrets. On the other hand, mentioning the sailor by himself feels odd. Example 2 is grammatically correct, but feels incomplete. "But" implies a thematic connection between the two halves of the sentence. What is it? And "...it is the sailor who..." leads us to expect more information about the sailor, as shown in example 4.

So in summary, I don't think the sentence is wrong, but I do think its meaning is fuzzy and I personally would try to reword it to communicate my point better.

Comment: Your point is well-said: *The change from 'who' to 'that' is as much a clue to a change of subject as the change from singular to plural.*

Comment: Sorry, seems like the title of the question was altered by someone. The identity of subject was not a concern, the concern was whether or not it was valid to refer to sailor doing the uncovering without an "s" on the verb. I returned the original title, sorry for misleading you.

Answer (score 2):

That Bot-Which-Must-Not-Be-Named here is correct — if you can understand *secrets* to be the antecedent for *them* and *that uncover them* to be a relative clause describing *storms* . . .

> *The depths hold secrets, but it is the sailor who braves [the storms that uncover them].* →
>
> *The depths hold secrets, but it is the sailor who braves [the storms that uncover secrets].* →
>
> *The depths hold secrets, but the sailor braves [the storms that uncover secrets].*

Comment: But the bot also claimed that "uncover" belongs to "sailor". So that part is wrong.

Comment: @Barmar — For what it’s worth... I just asked the bot about the grammar of the sentence and got a different interpretation than the OP. The interpretation had some flaws (e.g. calling *that* a conjunction) but did identify *storms* as the noun described by *that uncover them*. That made me wonder whether “the bot” could even be considered a single entity. I asked. “It” answered: *...I am not a single entity, but rather a collection of algorithms and data that have been combined in a specific way in order to perform a particular task.*

Comment: "That" **is** a subordinator in the OP's example. What else could it be? The more salient interpretation is that it is the sailor who uncovers the secrets. "The sailor [who braves the storms] [that uncovers them]" contains the 'stacking' of two relative clauses (bracketed), so the antecedent of the second relative clause is the singular "the sailor who braves the storms", thus the verb should be singular "uncovers".

Comment: @BillJ — Why would the sailor be a *who* in the first relative clause and a *that* in the second?

Comment: Probably to avoid repetition by using a _wh_ relative in the first and a _that_ relative in the second. Repeating "who" would be stylistically inelegant. I realise that there is another interpretation where "storms" is antecedent for the second relative clause, but it seems less likely to me. Who knows?

Answer (score 1):

1. The depths hold the secrets.
2. The storms uncover the secrets.
3. The sailor braves the storms.

The sailor braves the storms 
....that uncover the secrets
....that the depths hold.

If you run the sentence through [CMU’s online parser](https://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/submit-sentence-4.html), it gives this constituent tree:

```
(S (S (NP (NP The ocean 's)
          depths)
      (VP hold
          (NP secrets)
          (S (VP (ADVP yet)
                 to
                 (VP be
                     (VP discovered))))))
   , but
   (S (NP it)
      (VP is
          (NP (NP the sailor)
              (SBAR (WHNP who)
                    (S (VP braves
                           (NP (NP the storms)
                               (SBAR (WHNP that)
                                     (S (VP uncover
                                            (NP them)))))))))))
   .)
```

It is that parse which I have explained.

Comment: @fertilizerspike The parse tree is saying it's the storms **that** uncover them, not the sailor. The sailor is **who** braves the storms. I cannot comment on the sense, only on the syntax, and that's what the syntax is saying. If you're looking for linkage from *them* back to *secrets* or to *depths* or heaven forbid to *sailor*, then you need to use other tools or other displays than I have shown here with this simple tree. Being in separate enclosing sets of parentheses does not bar anaphor resolution.

Comment: "The sailor [who braves the storms] [that uncovers them]" contains the 'stacking' of two relative clauses (bracketed). The antecedent of the second relative clause is the singular NP "the sailor who braves the storms", thus the verb should be singular "uncovers".

Comment: @BillJ Why would *who* and *that* share the same referent?

Comment: "Who braves the storms" combines with it antecedent to form the larger unit "sailor who braves the storms" and this is then the antecedent for the second relative clause, "that uncovers them". Nothing unusual about it, but it comes with no guarantees!

Comment: @BillJ What you say almost makes sense. :) But what did you mean about it coming with no guarantees?

Comment: I mean the sentence could be ambiguous.  It's possible that the relative clauses are not stacked but independent, i.e the author intended the antecedent for the second relative clause to be "storms".

Comment: The "storms" is the obvious technical interpretation of of the subject of the "uncover" verb when you read the sentence, but the reason I asked the question is that it is obviously not the intended message, so I wondered if there is some ambiguity in parsing and some grammar rule (perhaps archaic) exists that makes the "sailor" also be an interpretation of the subject. By interrogating the bot, I got stuff like "the subject is the "secrets", they uncover themselves" and "the subject is the process of "braving"", but from all the answers, I guess it's more likely that bot is just mistaken.

Comment: Compares output from one grammar parser to output of a large language model chatbot that doesn't exploit grammar rules. Output also seems to conflict with passage created by the bot and question as formulated by Q and also conflicts with this A. Recommended action is remove parsing information or assertively characterize it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The would be fact that the storms uncover secrets make no sense at all; it has to be the sailor that uncovers them. Therefore an s is needed and someone made a mistake.

Comment: Storms can certainly uncover secrets. The tempest’s fury can raise them up from the depths where they previously lay hidden from view and in so doing reveal them to the sailor's eye.

Comment: @tchrist Storms at sea are a very superficial phenomenon that merely stir the surface of the waters; the treasures being referred to lie in the depths; and then, treasures, which  is mere ballast at the bottom of the sea, suddenly floating on the surface? What other possibility could it be ? I've never heard of pearls being washed ashore or floating on the surface, meerschaum, at best, can be collected on the surface, and it is not such a treasure….

Comment: @LPH ten second google search: https://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/927465/weather-redcar-beach-ancient-forest-unearthed-trees

Comment: @freedomn-m Then, how do you fathom those sailors  and their ships  braving storms as they wash away   sand from the littoral?

Answer (score -3):

I think it is being read to mean "sailor who is uncovered by the storms braves those storms", which is obviously a valid meaning. It's just failing to parse the nesting properly. Most humans would understand "secrets" can be uncovered by storms and "uncovering sailors" with a storm is a bizarre concept,  but large language models struggle with this kind of use.

Comment: Is there any reason to think that the word "them" in the original sentence refers to the sailor and not to the secrets?

Comment: This isn't really about what the sentence means, it's about how the language model parsed it to give apparently wrong advice.

Comment: I don't quite understand. What makes you suspect that the language model parsed the word "them" in the original sentence as referring to the sailor instead of the secrets?

Comment: It's parsing back and assigning it to the first candidate it finds in the clause after "but", "sailor uncovers them(neuter pronoun for sailor)"

Comment: That's the way i read the audit log but I'm no expert

Comment: Look at it this way, two procedures went on here, the bot constructed this turn of phrase, then the bot constructed more phrases that it thinks are an acceptable response to some question(s) along with it. The bot isn't consulting grammar rules to analyze the passage.

Comment: I did read the question, yes. Reading it again, I notice that the question says that "the bot claims that ‘uncover’ verb belongs to the ‘sailor’ [noun]." I interpreted the phrase "belongs to" as meaning that the sailor is the _subject_ of the verb "uncover"; maybe you interpreted it as meaning that the sailor is the object of that verb.